# Woocommerce Product Image White Dots Internet Explorer Error

Tags: image, jquery, woocommerce, image-size

I have an ecommerce website which uses Wordpress CMS and Woocommerce plugin.

The product images looks good on all the browsers except Internet Explorer.

When a category page loads, the product images have some white dots that disappear after the page completly loads. But on Internet Explorer the dots don't disappear.

I've read something about the jQuery fadeIn function. But I don't know the solution for this.

You can see below the problem:

[image]

Full screen image: [here](http://s16.postimg.org/j2w0rwpet/woocomerce_image_product_dots.jpg)

Still no answer. This is important. Any help will be great.

Comment: This is [not a WordPress question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: any idea regarding this error?

Comment: I've had a similar problem with user uploaded images on a CMS I used to work on. I found that opening the image in an image editor, like Photoshop, and then re-saving the image for web and re-uploading to the site often fixed the problem. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an Internet Explorer bug, which appears when using fadeIn animations. You have to adjust the black level of the image by replacing real black (`#000000`) with very dark gray (e.g. `#010101`).

You can use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) to replace the colors: `Colors > Map > Color Range Mapping`

More information [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?36674-White-dots-appear-on-some-images&p=161962#post161962), [here](http://www.alexjudd.com/judder/?p=5), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c815b68a-f253-4114-83a6-820af365390e/white-pixel-artefacts-in-fade-transition-filter-using-dximagetransformmicrosoftfade-on-ie7) and [here](http://support.bigblackbag.com/KB/a73/help-white-dots-appear-my-images-while-fading-internet.aspx).